# Cross Browser Font Display Test?

Tags: css, browser, fonts

Can someone please help me find a website which allows me to test how my website's font display on all modern (up to date) browsers?

I found, 
https://www.browserstack.com 
but I need to pay after I use 100 screenshots.
Isn't there a free option?

Is my best bet using "safe fonts" and copy code from here?
https://www.cssfontstack.com

It doesn't matter so much that my font displays *exactly the same* across all browsers, but I want to know what they look like at least.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you test in the actual browsers?